bug: "tagged questions" doesn't actually show all questions with that tag
I'm looking at the question Multi-round Transposition/Playfair as a secure hand cipher in the computer age .
When I click on the tag playfair at the end of that question,
I am taken to
https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/playfair
which has a list of some questions that have the "playfair" tag.
I expected that list to include all the questions tagged "playfair", including the original question I was looking at.
What I actually see is only 2 questions on that list,
"How many keys does the Playfair Cipher have?"
and
"How to attack a classical cipher using known partial plaintext?",
but not the original question.
Is this a bug, or is there some good reason that list doesn't show all the questions I expected it to show?
What should I do about it?

hmm, I see 9 questions.

Click on "newest" or "votes"

@mikeazo: Thank you for this work-around. When I click "newest" or "votes", I see many more questions. When I click "frequent", I see the same 2 questions I originally saw. I guess by default it shows me the "frequent" view? Even though you've given me a work-around, this still looks like a bug -- my understanding is that "newest", "frequent", "votes", etc. should each show all the questions, but sorted differently.

I think it actually defaults to what ever you used last.

This seems to be an issue that should be identical on all SE sites, so this is more on topic on meta.stackexchange.com rather than here.
